# Spring Security logout confirmation

Tags: spring-security, jsp-tags, logout

What is the best way to present a confirmation logout prompt with Spring Security?

I have a webapp and I can successfully call logout etc...
The Spring Sec configs then redirects the user back to the login page but I don't have a way to detect that this was a logout to present a prompt confirmation that the user has successfully logged out.

Any advice?

My Spring config below

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <http-basic />
    <remember-me user-service-ref="myDAO" />
    <form-login login-page="/" authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=1" default-target-url="/dashboard"
        always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are many ways you can approach this.

One obvious way is to have your own logout filter and logout handler.

I hope this thread on Spring forum fixes your problem

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?59277-Custom-Logout-Handler&p=236175#post236175

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to the logout-success-url and then check for them on the login page like this:

```
<logout logout-success-url="/?logout=success"/>
```

and on your page:

```
<c:if test="${param['logout'] == 'success'}">
    <div id="info-box">
        <p>You have been successfully logged out.</p>
    </div>
</c:if>
```